# How to skip NA values in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm applying a for loop to generate multiple API requests from the RePEc database. Unfortunately, the data is not reproducible because my access code the administrator gave me only works on my IP address but I'm hoping someone can help me figure out what I've done wrong in my for loop (I'm not great at writing for loops).

Basically, I have a column of 80,000 cells `df$author_reg_2`with a whole lot of NA values. I want to skip the NA values and only generate API requests for cells with an actual value in them.

```
url <- "https://api.repec.org/call.cgi?code=USERCODE&getauthorrecordraw="

affiliation_2 <-vector(length=length(df$author_reg_2))
for(i in 1:length(df$author_reg_2))
    try({
        Sys.sleep(1)
        if(is.na(df$author_reg_2)) next
        affiliation_fun <- paste0(url,df$author_reg_2[i])
        affiliation_run <- fromJSON(txt=affiliation_fun) %>% select("affiliation")
        affiliation_2[i] <- paste(unlist(affiliation_run), collapse =" ")
        print(i)
    })
```

Each time I try to run this script, it still generates errors telling me that it's running the NA values.

Any help appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you change `if(is.na(df$author_reg_2[i])) affiliation_2[i] <- NA else {affilation_run <- ...`

Comment: In your function the `if` statement should be for a single element instead of the whole column `if(is.na(df$author_reg_2)[i])`

Comment: Brilliant! That worked! Thank you so much @akrun So helpful as always!

Comment: Also, I guess it is better to initialize a `list`  i.e. `affiliation_2 <-vector("list", length=length(df$author_reg_2))` and in  the assignment  change `[i]` to `[[i]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we are looping over each element and passing the logic on `if`(takes a length of  1 and output 1), need the single element

```
url <- "https://api.repec.org/call.cgi?code=USERCODE&getauthorrecordraw="

affiliation_2 <-vector("list", length=length(df$author_reg_2))
for(i in seq_along(df$author_reg_2))
try({
    Sys.sleep(1)
    if(is.na(df$author_reg_2[i])) next
    affiliation_fun <- paste0(url,df$author_reg_2[i])
    affiliation_run <- fromJSON(txt=affiliation_fun) %>% select("affiliation")
    affiliation_2[[i]] <- paste(unlist(affiliation_run), collapse =" ")
    print(i)
})
```

The `list` would also hold `vector` of different `length` and there is no need to `paste` and  `collapse` at the end (if that is the case)

If we need to change `next` to have a `NA` value in `affliation_2

```
for(i in seq_along(df$author_reg_2))
    try({
        Sys.sleep(1)
        if(is.na(df$author_reg_2[i])) {
            affiliation_2[[i]] <-  NA_character_
           }  else{
            affiliation_fun <- paste0(url,df$author_reg_2[i])
            affiliation_run <- fromJSON(txt=affiliation_fun) %>% select("affiliation")
            affiliation_2[[i]] <- paste(unlist(affiliation_run), collapse =" ")
         }
        print(i)
    })
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I really appreciate it. Just one question. Is there any way of creating an empty cell every time the system encounters a NA value? The reason I ask is that i want to paste the values (affiliation_2) into a large dataframe next to the corresponding author, paper, etc. I need a way of somehow preserving the position of these values relative to their position in df.

Comment: @Oliver In that case instead of `next` you need `affliation_2[[i] <- NA` and the other code would be wrapped in `else`

Comment: OK that makes sense. Thanks. Do you know how I would do that in this case? I'm really bad at loops...

Comment: @Oliver Updated the post

Comment: Thank you so much!